# SQL Replaced Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to recover replaced Stored Procedure after restoration.
I forgot to create a backup before replacing the database.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems unlikely to me since you are effectively overwriting the whole database with the contents of the previously saved .bak-file. This kind of turns the clock backwards completely.

Comment: Thanks cars10, I am trying to check if there are cached or something i can use to get the scripts i needed but not 100% I can get the script

Comment: Only if you have the script stored somewhere outside the database, or if you can restore a database backup created before the change.

Comment: yup, I got some scripts but old one. I tried to update and deploy it to current database. Thanks @dean

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  This is a great example of why I advocate source control for database objects as well as compiled code.

Comment: It is utterly irresponsible to not put all database code in Source Control.

Answer (score -2):

@RexAtienza, If you have executed that SP recently then you can get that  from cache. Also look for any old backup of your DB where you can get your old SP.Check the below query to find out from cache.

```
SELECT DB_Name(qt.[dbid]) AS 'databaseName'
    ,Object_Name(qt.objectid, qt.[dbid]) AS 'procName'
    ,Max(qs.last_execution_time) AS 'last_execution'
    ,qt.TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt
where Object_Name(qt.objectid, qt.[dbid]) ='YOUR_PROC_NAME'
GROUP BY db_name(qt.[dbid])
    ,Object_Name(qt.objectid, qt.[dbid])
    ,qt.TEXT
ORDER BY databaseName
    ,procName
```

Comment: Wrong, "Restoring a database clears the plan cache for the instance of SQL Server." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Comment: @dean! I am saying to restore with different name(not overwrite) and get that stored procedure. use some "common sense"

Comment: Yes, but I was refering to the first part of your answer ("If you have executed that SP recently then you can get that from cache"). The OP already replaced the database - so, it's not in the cache any more.

Comment: Thanks, but my backup was 1 month ago, and the sp was created last week. Anyway thanks for the information I already recreated the scripts and created backup.

Comment: You need to look at your backup process in that respect. You should be able to recreate a production database from backups with no more than a 15 minute loss of time. Having a once a month backup is pretty much useless. What if you got a virus and had to rebuild the server?